# Backward compatibility testing

Tags: java, libraries, dependencies, backward-compatibility

As a creator of a software library, how can I verify backward compatibility with earlier versions?

When using a dependency management (here: Maven), multiple versions of my dependency could be (transitively) used:

```
com.example:some-project:jar:1.0.0
+- com.example:my-library:jar:1.1.0:compile
+- org.example:another-library:jar:1.0.0:compile
   \- com.example:my-library:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

As you can see, *some-project* is directly using *my-library*, but it is also a transitive dependency of *another-library* in an older version. Maven will include version 1.1.0 (see [dependency mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#transitive-dependencies)) and I want to ensure backwards compatibility between different minor versions so this is guaranteed to work (no accidental API changes from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0).

Are there any common practices to verify compatibility? All I can think of is some kind of smoketest script that builds such scenarios and tries to run them.

Comment: Could someone please explain what is wrong with this question? (-2)

Comment: maybe downvotes are because tools recommendations are off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Comment: @gnat Thanks for your hint. I removed that part.

Comment: I don't think it's really practical to verify compatibility in the true sense of having the correct behaviour. But it should be easy to check binary compatbility. I have previously used https://lvc.github.io/japi-compliance-checker/ which works well.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in such a scenario is create a separate project containing interface tests for version X. Once version X has been released, this test project should become effectively read-only.

When you are creating version X+1 that should be backward compatible with X, re-run the interface tests of version X in such a way that the project actually picks up version X+1 of the library. If the library is backward compatible, all tests should still pass.